# Login & Logout menu in only footer Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, menu, footer, logout

I want to get My account menu in only footer widget I'm using this code in functions.php to get different menus in footer widget when logged in and logged out:

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
} else { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

But My Account menu will change everywhere in top navigation, in other footer sections, how to get it work only in my specific footer widget?

Here is example, selected with red rectangle:
[image]

Comment: you mean specific theme location?

Comment: I've added example screenshot, in footer menu selected with red rectangle if I use my provided code all menus "Products" and others will change to My Account menu.